# Can I use vector of an object to store multiple types of objects that extends that object

Tags: java, generics, vector

Can I use vector of an object to store multiple types of objects that extends that object , say I have a class animal and two classes cat and dog, and I created a `vector<animal>` , and I want to do : `add(new dog())` ,and `add(new cat())` , is that possible ?

Comment: Hmm, how would you answer this? Is there any other way to find out? Just try it.

Comment: Given `l` of `ArrayList<Object>`, can you add a String to `l` (e.g. `l.add("string")`? And an Integer? That's the same question. (Also, consider not using Vector unless absolutely requiring it.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes; that's totally possible.

The whole point of inheritance is that a `Dog` *is* an `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

Yep.  This is referred to as [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), an important concept in computer science.

Based on your comment:

Class Dog and Cat both must inherit from Animal.  So, any child class (subtype) of animal can also function as an Animal.  A Dog is an Animal. A Cat is an Animal.  This is a simple example of polymorphism, and is useful as it gives you a lot of flexibility.  Any code which interacts with Animals can interact with any type of Animal!

If you ever need to access a method which doesn't exist in the Animal class, you'll need to cast to that specific type of Animal.  Here's an example.

```
Vector<Animal> vector = new Vector<Animal>();
vector.add(new Cat());
vector.add(new Dog());
//later on, maybe I need access to a cat specific method...
int wiskerCount = 0;
for(Animal animal : vector){
    if(animal instanceof Cat){
        Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
        whiskerCount += cat.getNumberWhiskers();
    }
}
```

Also, the `Vector` class is essentially just an `ArrayList` which is thread safe.  If you are not accessing this object from multiple threads, just use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Being able to pass a dog or a cat into a data structure of animal is a clear example of polymorphism.

Comment: Ok, ok, true. But do you have a more applicable term than polymorphism for this?

Comment: touché. Not off the top of my head :|

Comment: Perhaps just [subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), but that articles doesn't help any of my arguments.

Comment: i just figure it out, i know that its possible , but i didnt know how to implement it , this is the solution :
Vector <? super animal>v = new Vector<animal>();
 
 v.add(new dog());
 v.add(new cat());
and to know if the element is a cat or a dog :
if (v.elementAt(i) instanceof cat) {
  
   cat c1 = (cat)v.elementAt(i);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
//import java.util.*;
//Declare a default Vector

public static void printSampleElements(){
    Vector all = new Vector();
    all.add("Hello");
    all.add(10);
    all.add(true);
    for(int a = 0; a < all.size(); a++){
        out.println(all.get(a));
    }
}
```

The point is you can add pretty much anything into a vector.

Take a look at this.

```
v.add(new ArrayList <Integer>()); //add a blank list of ints.

ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList <>();
list.add(10);
list.add(20);

v.add(list); //add the list variable
```

You even add a ArrayList to a vector, although 2D Arrays would be much better.